# HCL Domino 11.0.1 JAR files missing. JARS were available in IBM Domino 9.0.1FP9

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, hcl

A number of JAR files present in our old IBM Domino 9.0.1FP9 environment appear to have gone missing after upgrading to HCL Domino 11.0.1. Specifically, the below list:

```
import com.ibm.commons.util.StringUtil;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;
import com.ibm.jscript.debug.ArrayListUtil;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.DataObject;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;
import org.openntf.xsp.debugtoolbar.beans.DebugToolbarBean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
```

I feel as though I'm missing something basic here, but have searched long and far for any HCL technotes on this.

Any suggestions on how/where/what I need to do in order to get these to resolve again?

Comment: I’m assuming that it’s Domino Designer that is complaining. This fix https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=JGAR-B9QL8B might resolve some of the missing imports

Answer (score 0):

Per, you're absolutely correct! Thank you.

My Notes Designer client, Release 11.0.1, actually showed 3 'Running Platform' entries with all 3 showing the identical location of --> ${eclipse_home} - C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse\1512 plug-ins available' listed.

The table also included 3 'Target Platform' entries listed below the 'Running Platform' entries as well.

However, all 3 of the 'Target Platform' entries had  location data showing.

The last 'Target Platform' entry was the entry that my preference was currently set to as being '(Active)'. I'm not sure how these entries are created -OR- which process decides which is '(Active)' and which is not. I know I didn't add and/or set them. :-)

When I chose the 1st 'Running Platform' entry instead, and made it my '(Active)' choice, and then clicked the 'Apply' button, then 'OK' to close the Preference dialog, the client immediately re-loaded the table and all but one Import statement resolved immediately.

The only one out my list shown in this thread that did NOT resolve was --> 'import org.openntf.xsp.debugtoolbar.beans.DebugToolbarBean'.

Here is a HCL Knowledge Base technote, authored by Paul Albright of HCL, on this very issue --> https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0081033&sys_kb_id=d4fd72c81b165890086dcbfc0a4bcb7c

QUESTION Follow-up: Is there any harm in deleting the extra duplicate entries from this preference table and only leave 1 'Running Platform' and 1 'Target Platform' entry?